# User Profile Service to Sharepoint Sync Not Updating userdisp.aspx

Tags: active-directory, profile-sync

We added a custom field Division to active directory.  The sync from AD to User Profile Service is working correctly, as our MySites correctly show this custom field populated as it should be.  Upon attempting to sync from User Profile Service to Sharepoint , this is somehow not working, we are getting no error logs, but **/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx** is not reflecting the changes we are pushing.

Does anyone perhaps have an idea of where we can go from here to fix this or figure out how to go about fixing this?

Comment: couple of things to check? is this for one user or all users? what permission level user have on the site collection? what are the content database in the sharepoint(check from central admin)?

Comment: This is designed for users of view permission levels all the way through full control